# Телеграм бот долго реагирует на команды

Tags: python, mysql, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите почему бот может долго реагировать на команду. После нажатия на кнопку проходит ~ 1 секунды, прежде чем бот выдаст ответ.

Такое ощущение, что он каждый раз подключается к бд, прежде чем выдать ответ. (возможно так и есть)

В плане подключения использую aiomysql.

```
import logging
import aiogram
import config
from synсtg import SyncTG
import importlib
import asyncio
import aiomysql
from config import DB_CONFS
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

# log level
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# bot init
bot = Bot(token=config.token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot)
sync_tg = SyncTG(config.token)

queue = []


async def creatPool() -> aiomysql.Pool:
    pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(host=DB_CONFS["host"], port=DB_CONFS["port"],
                                      user=DB_CONFS["user"], password=DB_CONFS["passwd"],
                                      db=DB_CONFS["database"], loop=loop, autocommit=True, pool_recycle=120)


    return pool


@dp.message_handler(content_types="text", text=" Топ")
async def top(message: types.Message):
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            try:
                await cursor.execute(f"SELECT status FROM users WHERE tguserid='{message.chat.id}'")
                st = await cursor.fetchall()
                if st[0][0] == 4:
                    await message.answer('⚠️ <b>Доступ запрещён</b> ⚠️', parse_mode='HTML')
                else:
                    top_d = ""
                    await cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY all DESC LIMIT 10")
                    users = await cursor.fetchall()
                    num = 1
                    for user in users:
                        top_d += f"<b>{num}. @{user[2]}</b> - <b>{user[3]}</b> логов\n"
                        num = num + 1
                    await message.answer('<b> Топ 10:</b>\n\n' + top_d, parse_mode='HTML')
            except:
                pass


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
pool: aiomysql.Pool = loop.run_until_complete(creatPool())
```

Comment: Методом исключений выяснил, что долгий ответ происходит из-за этой строчки:
`conn = await connection(loop)  # Создаем подключение с проверкой наличия таблицы`

Но как фиксануть всё равно не могу понять...

Comment: До сих пор не решил проблему.
Бот с базой sqlite отвечает на команду гораздо быстрее.
Это из-за того что база локальная?

Comment: В коде вопроса вообще нет такой строки, как в первом комментарии

Comment: @RomanKonoval, да, я немного поменял код. Ранее выглядело вот так - 
`@dp.message_handler(commands='stats')
async def seestat(message):
 conn = await connection(loop)  # Создаем подключение с проверкой наличия таблицы

 async with conn.cursor() as cursor:
  await cursor.execute(f"SELECT status FROM users WHERE tguserid = {message.chat.id}")
  status = await cursor.fetchall()`

Comment: Если от предыдущего запроса прошло больше 120 секунд, то в пуле не будет соединений и будет новое открываться. Не ваш случай? Пробовали не устанавливать `pool_recycle`?

Comment: @RomanKonoval, `pool_recycle=120`  я добавил только вчера. Потому-что если бот стоял некоторое время без обращения к бд, то потом он просто не реагировал. Это на самом деле никак не повлияло на скорость ответа бота.
У меня эта проблема уже порядка 20 дней.